# Virtual 2008 R2 on Hyper-V won't restart automatically - waits for recovery question to be asked

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

When I restart a Hyper-V host one or more of the attached virtual machines (Server 2008 R2) do not start up successfully, rather they pause waiting for the recovery dialogs to be either completed or cancelled. If I cancel the dialog the VM in question starts up fine.

This is less than optimum solution as I want the VM's to start upi without requiring any input from me.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Is the "recovery dialog" the one *inside* the guest (ie. guest OS saying something like "too many unexpected restarts")? Also what is the Automatic Stop Action for the guest set to?

Comment: the recovery dialog is inside the guest OS when it starts up. It shows me a drop down lsit of langugages to continue the recovery with. I choose to cancel the recovery and it starts normally.

Comment: the automatic stop action is "Turn off the virtual machine". Is this a bit harsh? Should it be "Shut down the guest operating system" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have essentially two options here.

1)  Reconfigure the OS within the guest VMs so that they don't drop into the recovery console after a hard reset.  See various bcdedit options for that.

For a full list of them, type:

> bcdedit /? types bootapp

Pay particular attention to "RECOVERYENABLED" and "RECOVERYSEQUENCE".

2)  Reconfigure the guest VMs themselves so that they don't experience a hard reset when you restart the host.  Under VM settings, see "Automatic Stop Action."  Set it to shut the VM down cleanly.

Personally, I prefer to do both.

Comment: thanks for the info. I have used been able to set the recvoeryenabled  = no on the VM and set the Automatic stop action to shut down the guest OS. Can/Should I also clear the RecoverySequence bcdedit setting, if how would I do that?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary.